# Reference Request: Gelfond Schneider Theorem

Tags: reference-request, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory, algebraic-numbers

I want to learn the background for the Gelfond Schneider Theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem

I want to learn the background needed for the proof of this theorem, as well as the proof itself. But I don't know what kind of textbook or class this would normally be covered in. Please recommend what I can study.

I want to be able to prove results on transcendence of specific numbers, which I know can be difficult in general. I also want to learn more about the subject in general, since my knowledge is very limited.

Thank you!!

Comment: Tubbs/Burger Making Transcendence Transparent has what you want: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4114-8

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what knowledge is assumed prior to reading this?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Beyond standard real analysis (integrals etc) Burger/Tubbs assume just some basic complex analysis, though most stuff is explained anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard introductory books I know about are [**Irrational Numbers**](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/niven.pdf) by Ivan Niven (1956; Gelfond-Schneider is the last chapter, Chapter X on pages 134-150) and [**Making Transcendence Transparent**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387214445) by Edward B. Burger and Rubert Tubbs (2004; Gelfond-Schneider is Chapter 5 on pages 113-146).

An expository paper on the proof is [*Gelfond's solution of Hilbert's seventh problem*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2302573) by Carl Einar Hille in **American
Mathematical Monthly** 49 #10 (December 1942), pp. 654-661.

Less elementary is [**Transcendental Number Theory**](http://www.infophysics.net/nt.pdf) by Alan Baker. However, instead of Baker's book, perhaps better for you would be the 1972 Master of Science thesis [**Transcendental Numbers and a Theorem of A. Baker**](https://escholarship.mcgill.ca/concern/theses/cr56n261n) by Cameron Leigh Stewart.